# Help me identify a fantasy book please

Tags: story-identification, novel

Fantasy novel that I once found at a library but for the life of me can't remember the name of the book or the author. It centers around a boy named Cain or CAne or KAin I believe and his two friends. It starts off with them being trained in some weird place by monks(?) and with a weird regime. He's a master martial artist. His two friends are a deformed archer kid and trained spy kid with a crossbow.

Does this ring any bells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds a bit like Paul Hoffman's book [The Left hand of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Left_Hand_of_God_(novel)). If it is this book the hero is Thomas Cale. His archer friend is Kleist, who isn't deformed but the book does say:

> His right arm and shoulder in particular were so much more knotted with muscle than his left side that he looked almost deformed.

His other friend is Vague Henri, however he's an assassin not a spy. There isn't that much in the book about him, but there is a description:

> “Vague Henri is what the Materazzi call . . .” He lost the word and began searching. “A cecchino . . . a hit man. The crossbow is all he ever uses."

Cale is brought up by a religious group who call themselves The Redeemers. It is a sort of monastic setting.